# Ho to get/return a single dictionary by applying function on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have following dataframe :

```
state  city     alt_city
FL  FT. PIERCE  FORT PIERCE
FL  FT. PIERCE  FORTPIERCE
FL  FT. PIERCE  FT.PIERCE
FL  FORT PIERCE FORTPIERCE
FL  FORT PIERCE FT PIERCE
FL  FORT PIERCE FT. PIERCE
FL  FORT PIERCE FT.PIERCE
FL  FORT PIERCE FTPIERCE
AK  ANCHORAGE   ANCH
AK  ANCHORAGE   ANCHORAGE
```

and I want to genearte a dictionary from it based on certain conditions:

Following is a pseudo code :

```
def map_df_to_dict(d,state,city,alt_city):
    key1 = (state,city)
    val1 = alt_city
    key2 = (state,alt_city)
    val2 = city
    if key1 in d:
        d[key1].append(val1)
    else:
        d[key1] = []
        d[key1].append(val1)
    if key2 in d:
        d[key2].append(val2)
    else:
        d[key2] = []
        d[key2].append(val2)
    return d
```

If I apply it on dataframe using following code :

```
cs_d = {}
cs_dict = df.apply(lambda x: map_df_to_dict(cs_d,x['state'],x['city'],x['alt_city']), axis=1)
```

then it will return dictionary for every row in the dataframe.

But how can I apply this on a dataframe so that it will not return weird results.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I've added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe.apply runs the function for each row (or column).
That's why you get multiple dicts.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

`DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)`

Applies function along input axis of DataFrame.

Objects passed to functions are Series objects having index either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the columns (axis=1).

**Parameters: func : Function to apply to each column/row**

Answer (score 0):

You can get a single dictionary by declaring the dictionary "globally" outside the scope of your function. Consider the following pseudo code to add 2 to each number in a pandas Series.

```
test_a = pd.Series([1,2,3])
global_dict = {}

def add_2(x):
    global_dict[x] = (x+2)
```

When I apply this function on test_a, I get the below result:

```
test_a.apply(add_2)
print(global_dict)
```

global_dict = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5}

Hope this helps.